# CORS config on google bucket

Tags: python, cors, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to set CORS config on google bucket. I am referring https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-bucket-cors. Can someone help me with how to use this request in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the JSON API instead, and use the [google-cloud-storage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud-storage) library. Documentation for Bucket is [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-buckets.html).

I haven't tried this, but something like:

```
from google.cloud import storage

bucket = storage.Client().get_bucket('bucket-id-here')
bucket.cors = [{
  origin: ['*', ...],
  method: ['GET', ...],
  responseHeader: ['some-resp-header', ...],
  maxAgeSeconds: 86400, # one day
}]
bucket.patch()  # Send the update
```

Comment: I tried the above suggestion, but it was not updated for the bucket on storage. Can you help me with some additional information.

Comment: It might be necessary to call [patch](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.patch) on the bucket to send the update.

Comment: can you share your views on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43405755/gcp-access-control-allow-headers

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests Indicates that header is not allowed without a preflight request, which presumably GCS is not serving to allow that header.